# Dichotomize data by factor

Tags: r, median, r-factor, categorization

I need to create a dichtomized variable based on two factors (one hopes it's possible).

Let's say I have the data:

```
    d <- data.frame ( 
    agegroup = c(2,1,1,2,3,2,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,3) ,
    gender = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1) , 
    hourwalking = c(0.3,0.5,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.3,1.5,1.7,1.8,2.1,2.1,2.2,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.4,3,3.1,3.1,4.3,5)        
    )
```

I would like to create a binary (LowWalkHrs) using the gender- and agegroup-specific median (e.g., when agegroup = 1 and gender = 1, median = 2.1 (median was found using excel)). The LowWalkHrs would be an added variable in the dataset, so the output would be:

```
     agegroup gender hourwalk LowWalkHrs
        2       2       0.3       1
        1       2       0.5       1
        1       2       1.1       0
        2       2       1.1       1
        3       2       1.1       1
        2       2       1.2       0
        1       1       1.2       1
          ....
        3       1       5         0
```

I have a rather large dataset (~10k observations), so Excel is out of the question.

In R I've tried cut and cut2, which doesn't seem to take factor variables, as well  ddply, which gave me an error message of (Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "lowWalkHrs", value = list(hourwalking = c(0.63,  :  replacement has 949 rows, data has 11303).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this might be slow, but I think it works:

```
z <- mapply(d$agegroup, d$gender, d$hourwalking, FUN=function(a,g,h)
    as.numeric(h < median(d$hourwalking[d$agegroup==a & d$gender==g])) )
```

Comment: It does work, I haven't tried it on the larger dataset, but I will. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, tried it with the larger dataset, and I get the error message:      Error in mapply(d$agegroup, d$gender, d$hourwalking,  : 
  Zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length. I do have missing data in my larger dataset, is this what's causing the error?

Comment: Yea, the stuff in `[...]` won't work well with missing values.

Comment: Fixed the first problem....the error message is now: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'.

Comment: how did you incorporate `is.na`?

Comment: Just needed a "na.rm=TRUE"

Answer (score 2):

```
d <- data.frame ( 
    agegroup = c(2,1,1,2,3,2,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,3) ,
    gender = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1) , 
    hourwalking = c(0.3,0.5,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.3,1.5,1.7,1.8,2.1,2.1,2.2,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.4,3,3.1,3.1,4.3,5)        
   )

d$LowWalkHrs=1*with(d,hourwalking<ave(hourwalking,list(factor(agegroup,exclude=NULL),factor(gender,exclude=NULL)),FUN=median))
```

factor(...,exclude=NULL) added for treating NA's as separate group.